# linkbutton with multiple link options

Tags: asp.net

I have two files for this year and next year, and the linkbutton has to point to the different file depends on the year. But the problem is we want to open the file in a new window. So I decide to call javascript from the server side

code for asp:linkbutton

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="guide" runat="server" Text="XXX" OnClick="guide_click">
```

javascript code

```
function Guidelink2013() {
        window.open('XXX1.pdf', '', 'width=750,height=900'); return false;
}
function Guidelink2012() {
         window.open('XXX2.pdf', '', 'width=750,height=900'); return false;
}
```

code behind

```
    protected void guide_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["YearLastLicence"] != null)
        {
            if (int.Parse(Session["YearLastLicence"].ToString()) < DateTime.Now.Year)
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:Guidelink2012();", true);
            }
            else ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:Guidelink2013();", true);

        }
    }
```

It works fine when first opening the page, but if I refresh the page, the pop up window will open automatically as well. Any idea? thanks

Comment: why not send pdf name as a parameter to javascript function instead of writing two functions which are nearly identical except the pdf name? This would save you 4 or 5 lines of codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write the code in the page load and not in the click event of the link button.

So on page load,

```
 if (Session["YearLastLicence"] != null)
        {
            if (int.Parse(Session["YearLastLicence"].ToString()) < DateTime.Now.Year)
            {
               guide.Attrbuites.Add("onclick","javascript:Guidelink2012();return false;");
            }
            else {
guide.Attrbuites.Add("onclick" "javascript:Guidelink2013();return false;");

        }
}
```

You can also remove the click event from the Linkbutton.

Comment: should be "Attributes". It works, can you explain a little bit more why  it didn't work correctly in onclick event?

Comment: on the onclick event, you were doing  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript which registers an event to be run during the Page Load on the client. so as soon as you click on the link button, it postbacks and the runs the script, but later post backs will not have this info and will not open the popoup. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Also do make the reply as answer, so other people can find it useful! :)